# no edge is getting stored in my multigraph

Tags: c++

I am trying to make multi-weighted graphs.
**Input is to be made in following way**

1. Firstly user number of vertex user want  and
2. The ith line of a programmer's map contains details of the vertex
   directly accessible from room i .  for ex

**5**
**a 2**  *//  (vertex 1 is connected to vertex 2 by edge having weight 'a')*
**t 5 r 4** *//  (vertex 2 is connected to vertex 4 an by edge having weight 't'and'r')*
**a 4**
**r 2 t 3**
**b 5 i 5 o 5**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
struct maps{
 vector<char> weight;   //for storing multiple-edge and self-loop![enter image description here][1]
};
void input_edge(int n,maps m[10][10])
{
 std::string user_input;
 std::istringstream iss(user_input);
 char letter;// for making tokens 
 int index; // for making tokens
 int i;
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{ std::getline(std::cin, user_input);
  while (iss >> letter >> index)
  m[i][index].weight.push_back(letter);
}
}
int main()
{ int n;//no.of vertex user want to make graph
  cin>>n;
  cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
  maps m1[10][10];
  input_edge(n,m1);
  int i,j; 
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
  {cout<<"no of edge between vertex"<<i<<' '<<"and"<<' '<<j<<':'<<m1[i][j].weight.size()<<endl;}//to find no of edge between 2 vertex
}
```

but i am getting incorrect outputs.please tell how to fix it..

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTgeD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't quite understand the use of `istringstream`. On this line `std::istringstream iss(user_input);` you fill in all the content you will read from the input string stream. From then on nevermind how many things you read in `std::getline(std::cin, user_input);` you never change the contents of `iss`, meaning that the input string stream will never serve you anything but nulls. Change your code like that:

```
void input_edge(int n,maps m[10][10])
{
 std::string user_input;

 char letter;// for making tokens 
 int index; // for making tokens
 int i;
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{ std::getline(std::cin, user_input);
  std::istringstream iss(user_input);
  while (iss >> letter >> index)
  m[i][index].weight.push_back(letter);
}
```

And see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing `iss` too early which results in `iss` being an "empty stream".  Moving the `iss` declaration line right after the call to `getline` should help.